# Python library for writing WAV file metadata

Tags: python, wav

I'm looking for a python library for writing metadata (the "info" or "list" fields, I believe) to RIFF WAV files. I had assumed this would be easy, but I've looked at the ones I could find and haven't been able to find a solution. For example:

- the `wave` module
- `scipy.io.wavfile`
- `SoundFile`

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'd prefer not to hack with structs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ?

It is able to read as well as to write to tags, and RIFF/WAVE is supported

https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/wave.html

Comment: While WAVE support is in the documentation, I get a module not found error, and looking more, it appears that it is not yet (fully)supported: https://github.com/metabrainz/picard/pull/1532